# Add-Content to txt

Tags: powershell, text-files

I'm trying to make a GUI that will print the information from a textbox into a .txt in a way that I will try to explain as well as I can.

```
$TextBox_UsbName.text = "TestingTesting"

$Button_SetUsbName.Add_Click({ $Value_UsbName = $TextBox_UsbName.text; add-content -path $Value_NewScriptPath -value "$usbname  = $Value_UsbName" })
```

After this is run I was hoping the text file would contain this:

```
$usbname = "TestingTesting"
```

I am still new to Powershell as well as coding in general and now I am really stuck I have tried a lot of different ways.

Any ideas and help would be much appreciated.

Edit: My result is

```
=
```

Comment: You don't say what result you actually get, but at a guess I think the `$` is causing a problem.  Try escaping the first `$` with a backtick.  e.g.  `"\`$usbname  = $Value_UsbName"`

Comment: That helped now my result is       $usbname  =

Comment: Does this help? "`$usbname  = $($TextBox_UsbName.text)"

Comment: Yes I think I misspelled something so that the "TestingTesting" wasn't defined right, the backtick helped my second problem and got the $usbname to show... So thanks for the help now i can continue my GUI :)

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell double quoted string literals, string interpolation takes place each time an unescaped `$` appears with a valid identifier characters after it. To introduce a literal `$` that should not be parsed as part of an interpolated variable, you should escape it with a backtick, **`` ` ``**.

Here is [some quick string interpolation help](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/):

> How do I expand an expression in a string?
>   Windows PowerShell will expand a variable or an expression in  a string. 
>   Variables look like:          `$variable`
>   Expressions look like:  `$(expression)`

So, your `"$usbname  = $Value_UsbName"` is interpreted by the engine as *value of `$usbname` variable* followded with `=` enclosed with spaces, and then *a value of `$Value_UsbName` variable*.

What you want to add is a literal `$usbname` substring and the value of `$TextBox_UsbName.text` expression.

So, either use

```
"`$usbname = $($TextBox_UsbName.text)"
```

Or just concatenate values (in a culture independent way):

```
$usbname + ' = ' + $TextBox_UsbName.text
```